# jQuery Div shrinks when moving to the right but not to the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[I'm working on this page you can see here.](https://material-for-fba-trimakas.c9users.io/) When you click on `Let's Get Started` and then the subsequent right chevrons, the div's move to the left nicely and do not shrink. However, if you click the "back" or left pointing chevrons the div moves to the right like it should, but it also shrinks, which I do not want.

How can I make the divs moving to the right NOT shrink? I've changed the css so that the div does not move all the way off the page so you can see what's happening.

Here is the my jQuery that's doing the work:

```
function forward(){
  console.log("forward ran");
  // debugger;
  console.log("in forward page is " + page + " before adding");  
  $('#' + page).addClass( "gone_left", 1000, "swing" );
  page = page + 1;
  $('#' + page).removeClass("gone_left gone_right");
  console.log("in forward page is " + page + " after adding");
  manageChevrons();
}

function back(){
  console.log("back ran");
  // debugger;
  console.log("in back page is " + page + " before adding");   
  $('#' + page).addClass( "gone_right", 1000, "swing");
  page = page - 1;
  $('#' + page).removeClass("gone_left gone_right");
  manageChevrons();
}
```

`manageChevrons` just manages the right and left chevrons.

Then my CSS

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px){
html {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.no_overflow {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.gone_left {
    left: -5% !important;
}

.gone_right {
    left: 90% !important;
}

.card_center {
  position: absolute !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) !important;
    left: 50%;
}
```

And finally the HTML of the page

```
<html>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body class="no_overflow">

  <div class="container top-pad">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s4">
        <%= image_tag "logo.png", class:"responsive-img" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row valign-wrapper">
    <div class="left_chevron">
      <i id="chevron_left" class="waves-effect waves-circle large material-icons purple-text text-darken-4 hidden left_chevron">chevron_left</i>
    </div>

      <div id="3" class="card large card_center">
        <div class="card-image">
          <%= image_tag "3.png" %> 
          <span class="card-title"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content card_position">
          <p>This is #4
            <ul>US: xxx</ul>
            <ul>EU: xxx</ul>  
          </p>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- end of fourth card -->

      <div id="2" class="card large card_center">
        <div class="card-image">
          <%= image_tag "2.png" %> 
          <span class="card-title"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content card_position">
          <p>You will need to get carrier calculated shipping
            enabled on your store. Its free if you signed
            up for the annual plan, otherwise its just $20/month.
            Call Shopify to enable it:
            <ul>US: xxx</ul>
            <ul>EU: xxx</ul>  
          </p>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- end of third card -->

      <div id="1" class="card large card_center">
        <div class="card-image">
          <%= image_tag "1.png" %> 
          <span class="card-title"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content card_position">
          <p>For $25/month we fulfill an unlimited number of
            orders, so you don't have too.</p>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- end of second card -->      

      <div id="0" class="card large card_center">
        <div class="card-image"> 
          <%= image_tag "hi.png" %> 
          <span class="card-title"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content card_position">
          <p>Welcome to FBA Shipping by ByteStand.
            A super simple way to automate fulfilling FBA items
            in the US and abroad.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <button id="first_button" class="waves-effect btn stroke-btn tap">Let's Get Started!</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- end of first card -->


    <div class="right_chevron">
      <i id="chevron_right" class="waves-effect waves-circle large material-icons purple-text text-darken-4 hidden right_chevron">chevron_right</i>
    </div>
    </div> <!-- end of main row -->
  </div> <!-- end of container -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the CSS class called `.card`, remove `"max"` from `"max-width:500px;"`

so essentially just make it `"width:500px;"` and thats it.

Comment: Booyah! Thank you so much, just saved about 5 hours of time!! I'll accept this answer once it lets me.